# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while deploying the war file in Heroku

Tags: java, spring, maven, heroku

While trying to deploy my Spring MVC Application war file to Heroku I am getting java.lang.OutofMemoryError Exception. What may be the reason for this exception? What am I doing wrong?

```
C:\Users\sai\Desktop>heroku deploy:war --war crud-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war --app  springmvc-crud-jpa
Uploading crud-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war....
---> Packaging application...
     - app: springmvc-crud-jpa
     - including: webapp-runner.jar
     - including: crud-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war
     - installing: OpenJDK 1.8
---> Creating slug...
     - file: slug.tgz
     - size: 68MB
---> Uploading slug... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.PosterOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.Curl.put(Curl.java:75)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.Slug.upload(Slug.java:81)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.App.uploadSlug(App.java:196)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.App.deploySlug(App.java:186)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.App.createAndReleaseSlug(App.java:169)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.App.deploy(App.java:83)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.App.deploy(App.java:87)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.WarApp.deploy(WarApp.java:32)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeployWar.main(DeployWar.java:51)
---> Done
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error (64MB heap size)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of the [heroku-deploy](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-deploy) plugin. I've increased the default heap size for the tool, so if you reinstall it by running `heroku plugins:install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-deploy` and then deploy again, it will hopefully work.

If other continue to encounter this, you can manually increase the heap size even further by setting the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable with something like `-Xmx2g`.